# Need road condition data for the Washington DC area

Tags: data-request, weather, transportation, traffic

I am taking a data science class and we are supposed to develop our own final project idea.

The general context of the idea I am considering is that there is a group that meets once per week. Based on various features, I would like to see if it would be possible to predict the attendance. One factor, which may be difficult to obtain, that would affect attendance would be the road conditions. For example, several days after a big snow storm or during one, the attendance would be affected. I figure there is a chance such data would be available, as it would be for the Washington DC metro area, but I am not sure where I might find it.

Comment: Have you searched for recent or historical weather data?

Comment: Many states have a "road conditions" map (and Google has traffic maps). https://search.usa.gov/search?query=road+conditions&affiliate=dc_dcgov may or may not be helpful (dc.gov is the main site for DC). You may also see if Maryland or Virginia road condition maps/data cover DC because of its unusual status.

Answer (score 1):

http://biz.weather.com/WU-Data-API_Data-Package-Demo-Request.html looks like it may have all the data you need. Having said that, I'm viewing this on a small display so I can't tell if there is any free access to this.

Answer (score 1):

[opendata.dc.gov](http://opendata.dc.gov/) actually has some really nice datasets. DC is also a great choice for this, because it has so much good data over a very small area.
[Code for DC](https://codefordc.org/) has a lot of data too, but unfortunately their data portal seems to be down. You could join their Slack channel and ask them directly, or even [stand up their portal](https://github.com/codefordc/opendatadc) yourself.
I'm not 100% they have the data your desire exactly; another bonus of asking in the Slack channel is there are many different groups vested within Code for DC (DataKindDC is one off the top of my head) that could possibly also have what you want.